# Grouped accesses into security ODOO 13

Tags: xml, security, odoo-13

I want to group the accesses each type of group to a parent groupas the picture 
in odoo 13 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code to create category

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_custom">
        <field name="name">Custom Category</field>
        <field name="description">Custom</field>
        <field name="sequence">1</field>
    </record>
```

Please use the below coed in xml.

`<field name="category_id" ref="Parent Category"/>`

For example:

---

```
<record id="group_account_invoice" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Billing</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_accounting_and_finance"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

---

```
<record id="new_group_id" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">New Group Name</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module.module_category_custom"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

Give this xml file in manifest

Comment: Thank you @Anitha Das B for your answer, I want to know how to add the accee of this group (group_account_invoice) for example in the type 'Accounting'? how to organize everyone in a category like in the 'Sale' I find - sale + point of sale

Comment: hi thank 
look the img , i have edit , I want added like that then a category as you showed me

Comment: Please look in to the answer, as I have made some edits regards your doubt